# How can I parse aws api date string?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js

When I use the aws codecommit api to select one commit I recieve the following json response:

```
{
  "commit": {
    "additionalData": "",
    "committer": {
      "date": "1505892072 +0200",
      "name": "some name",
      "email": "some@email.com"
    },
    "author": {
      "date": "1505892072 +0200",
      "name": "some name",
      "email": "some@email.com"
    },
    "treeId": "c06c3kr2890sdf80f4e7f1234998cc18c2d672a6",
    "parents": [
      "8jghe808f7f5acc8f067dfg73f88ebfc6e5dfg82"
    ],
    "message": "some message"
  }
}
```

Now I want to parse the commit date `1505892072 +0200` in javascript. For this the function `Date.parse(commtiDate)` doesn't work because of the confusing format of the date.

In the example response of the AWS documentation it seems as if the format below is the standard format for api response ([code commit api reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/APIReference/API_GetCommit.html)).

Have someone an idea how this format works and how to parse it in javascript?

Comment: It looks like the `timestamp` + `timezone code`, you could split by ` ` & convert

Comment: But I think the first part of the string is the a timestamp and `Date.parse("1505892072")` dosent work.

Comment: new Date("1505892072")?

Comment: As I checked, the api returns the timestamp respective to UTC & the 2nd part is the UTC & current time zone difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about the +0200 but check the following:

```
var seconds = "1505892072";
var d = new Date(0);
d.setUTCSeconds(seconds);
```

Possible timezone adjustments still to be made ;)

Comment: @MatzeG. Great to hear :)